# Disable dates in a jquery datepicker dynamically

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker

```
var birthDate;
$(function() {
    var currentDate = new Date();
    $("#BirthDate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "../Images/cal.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        maxDate: currentDate,
        yearRange: "-90:+10",
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { birthDate = dateText;}
    });
});
$(function() {
    var currentDate = new Date();
    $("#MaritalStatusDate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "../Images/cal.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        minDate: birthDate,
        maxDate: currentDate,
        yearRange: "-90:+10"
    });

});
```

In the above code I am trying to disable `$("#MaritalStatusDate")` dates based on the date selected in `$("#BirthDate")`. I am using the `onSelect` event in `BirthDate` to identify the selected date and I'm storing the value in a variable which is globally declared. Using the variable I have set the `minDate` in `$("#MaritalStatusDate")`.                                                         But the dates are not getting disabled based on `minDate` value. Do I need to change the date format while assigning the value to the variable? Can anyone please help me in doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply set the `minDate` for `$('#MaritalStatusDate')` in `onSelect` event.

```
$("#BirthDate").datepicker({
    ...
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        $('#MaritalStatusDate').datepicker('option', 'minDate', dateText);
    }
});
```

See this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/william/2q7TN/.

Comment: hi william. I used your script.but when click the submit button and get back to the view, the datepickers are not displaying.

Comment: @kavithaReddy, i'm not sure what you mean. Are you able to illustrate it via jsfiddle?